# Disable cron jobs for a specific user

Tags: cron, crontab

I have a list of jobs in the crontabs for `user1`, `user2`. I want to prevent the jobs of `user2` from running.

I tried listing `user2` in `cron.deny`, but that only prevents him from accessing his `crontab`. The  jobs listed in `user2`'s `crontab` still get executed.

How do I disable cron jobs for a specific user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brute force!

```
crontab -u fred -e
%s/^/#/
:wq
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but unless you are doing this all the time, use the hammer you have.

Comment: I was doing it the same way. Was wondering if `cron` should have this feature integrated.

Comment: can you explain what this does/how it solves the issue?

Comment: @PsychoData: It comments-out all scheduled tasks for the specified user. See `man crontab` and `man vi`: `%`= every line, `s/a/b/`=substitute b for first a, `^`=start of line. Lines starting with `#` are ignored by cron.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to disable the crontab for a specific user is to locate her **crontab** and rename it. The Debian man page for **cron** says:

```
cron searches its spool  area  (/var/spool/cron/crontabs)  for  crontab
files  (which  are named after accounts in /etc/passwd); crontabs found
are loaded into memory.
```

So just rename the file to something that is not in the passwd, usually by giving it a suffix like `disabled`, `offline`, `dead` or similar.

```
mv -vi /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user2 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user2.disabled
```

On Debian (and related systems like Ubuntu) this produces the following entry in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
(user2.disabled) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
```

Make sure to also add `user2` to the file `/etc/cron.deny`, otherwise the user will be able to create a new crontab for herself.

Re-enable the user's crontab by deleting the entry from `/etc/cron.deny` and renaming her crontab:

```
mv -vi /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user2.disabled /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user2
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `/var/spool/cron/user1` or `user2` ? and you also want to add these user names to `/etc/cron.deny` otherwise they can add those cron jobs back

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -r username` works on Solaris to remove the crontab for a given username.

If `-r` doesn't work for you, then try:

`su username 'sh -c "crontab /dev/null"'`

Quicker to type and easier to script than `crontab -e`.

Comment: The problem with this is that it destroys the user's information, which you probably shouldn't do unless you're dealing with a hostile user (and perhaps not even then). The other answer just comments out the user's crontab, which strikes me as a better idea.

Comment: As @KeithThompson says, I do not want to erase the crontab for that user. I just want to disable it. The use case is such that I'd like to enable it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block the crontab job for a particular user make sure that your logged in with root user,root user only have access for crontab files.
1.Then go to the dir /etc/cron.d in this directory you can see that cron.deny file,make an enter of particular user name which user want to block by using vi editor or orther.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.